# Does CP symmetry dictates that a particle and its antiparticle behave the same when moving in opposite directions and how can I observe CP asymmetry?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, antimatter, matter, cp-violation

I have started reading in particle physics very recently. I have been reading a bit about tau particles, and I came across the idea of CP symmetry and how it’s violation may present an explanation for matter-antimatter asymmetry in the universe.

I read a simple explanation for CP symmetry stating that, for example, an electron and a positron moving in opposite directions with the same velocity behave exactly the same. However, we now know that not all particles obey this symmetry since CP asymmetry has been observed in Kaons and vaguely in quarks.

My knowledge is that tau particles are formed by the collision of an electron and a positron with $E_{com}$ that is twice the mass of a tau particle, forming a tau and its antiparticle. My question is can we observe how different these two particles may behave when going in opposite directions, in their mode of decay for instance, and check whether they are asymmetric? Is such an experiment correct or is their something wrong with my understanding of CP symmetry? Also, what other factors I may focus on to check whether they act symmetrically or asymmetrically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look here: [CP violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation) (Wikipedia)

Comment: Do you want to tell if there is a violation just from their motion it does not seem possible. Also we have few, if any, observations of CP violation in leptons, better check quark composed systems.

Comment: @Mauricio this idea came to me when I read about T2K experiment, where they detected unequal amounts of electron neutrinos reaching their detectors. Therefore, I though of doing a similar analysis to Tau particles to check for asymmetry. I’m not detecting it from motion but from decay modes. Also, I asked whether there is something else that I may follow along decay modes that my signify asymmetry

Comment: Then you just apply the same analysis as in the T2K experiment with taus and tau (anti)neutrinos instead of muons and muon (anti)neutrinos

Comment: @Mauricio I’m trying to approach the problem differently. Is there anything wrong with my idea?

Comment: It seems to me from your question you have not read the link provided, where the history of CP symmetry and its violations are clearly stated. You have to understand that all these concepts depend drastically on quantum mechanics and its probabilistic predictions. Measuring  single particles interactions conservation laws of energy momentum charge etc quantum numbers control the behavior os single particles. It is in observing accumulation of same type of events that the probabilistic nature of particle interactions can be studied, and CP symmetry observed as recorded.